# -Filter "LocalAccount='$True' Placement

Tags: powershell, foreach, get, admin

I am having an issue in this power shell script getting the script to oly look at the local accounts on the system.  As written it polls AD for every computer and that would put way too much strain on AD.  I believe I need to add -Filter "LocalAccount='$True' for the Get-Wmiobject but cant seem to get it in the right place.  Any assistance or advice is appreciated.  Also I thing that this script is actually doing the work twice to produce a csv output, any suggestions?

```
$Computers = Get-QADComputer -SizeLimit 0 | select -Expand name
    }


function Get-Admins {

Foreach ($Computer in $Computers){
$Online = Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Quiet
    if ($Online -eq "True"){
    $GroupName = Get-WmiObject win32_group -ComputerName  $Computer | ? {$_.SID -eq 'S-     1-5-32-544'} | Select-Object name -ExpandProperty name
    $LocalGroup =[ADSI]"WinNT://$Computer/$GroupName"
    $GroupMembers = @($LocalGroup.psbase.Invoke("Members"))
    $Members = $GroupMembers | foreach {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name",   'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}
    foreach ($Member in $Members){
    $obj = New-Object System.Object
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Computer" -Value $Computer
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Local Admin" -Value $Member
    $obj
        }
    }
}
 }


Get-Admins | group { $_.Computer } | ForEach-Object {
  $computer = @($_.Group | Select-Object -Expand Computer)[0]
  $admins   = ($_.Group | Select-Object -Expand "Local Admin") -join ','
   '{0},{1}' -f $computer, $admins
 } | Out-File 'c:\scripts\CSV_Admin_export.csv'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can simplify it a lot with changing Get-WmiObject call to:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Group -Filter "LocalAccount = $true AND SID = 'S-1-5-32-544'"
```

As you can see, istead of using `Where-Object` to filter out only SID you care about, I've used WMI filter for that too.

For filter you've asked for, any of below would work:

```
    "LocalAccount = 1"
    "LocalAccount = TRUE"
    "LocalAccount = 'TRUE'"
    "LocalAccount = $true"
    "LocalAccount = '$true'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the Administrators group on the target machine using a filter:

```
$GroupName = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Group -Filter "Domain='$Computer' AND SID='S-1-5-32-544'" -ComputerName $Computer).Name
```

Comment: Unless your windows is not EN-* and your administrators group name is something different...? ;) There is really good reason why people use SID, not name, localization is one thing. Renaming this group would be another reason to use this approach.

Comment: Agree, I didn't take this into account.